# How to find the most similar molecule to the actual drug having this data?

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, machine-learning

I have been trying to select the most similar molecule in the data below using python. Since I'm new to python programming, I couldn't do more than plotting. So how could we consider all factors, such as surface area, volume, and ovality,  for choosing the best molecule? The most similar molecule should replicate the drug V0L in all aspects. **V0L IS THE ACTUAL DRUG (the last row),** *The rest are the molecules*.

```
    Mol   Su     Vol        Su/Vol  PSA      Ov     D   A     Mw    Vina

 1.  1  357.18  333.9   1.069721473 143.239 1.53    5   10  369.35  -8.3
 2.  2  510.31  496.15  1.028539756 137.388 1.68    6   12  562.522 -8.8
 3.  3  507.07  449.84  1.127223013 161.116 1.68    6   12  516.527 -9.0
 4.  4  536.54  524.75  1.022467842 172.004 1.71    7   13  555.564 -9.8
 5.  5  513.67  499.05  1.029295662 180.428 1.69    7   13  532.526 -8.9
 6.  6  391.19  371.71  1.052406446 152.437 1.56    6   11  408.387 -8.9
 7.  7  540.01  528.8   1.021198941 149.769 1.71    7   13  565.559 -9.4
 8.  8  534.81  525.99  1.01676838  174.741 1.7     7   13  555.564 -9.3
 9.  9  533.42  520.67  1.024487679 181.606 1.7     7   14  566.547 -9.7
 10. 10 532.52  529.47  1.005760477 179.053 1.68    8   14  571.563 -9.4
 11. 11 366.72  345.89  1.060221458 159.973 1.54    6   11  385.349 -8.2
 12. 12 520.75  504.36  1.032496629 168.866 1.7     6   13  542.521 -8.7
 13. 13 512.69  499     1.02743487  179.477 1.69    7   13  532.526-8.6
 14. 14 542.78  531.52  1.021184527 189.293 1.71    7   14  571.563 -9.6
 15. 15 519.04  505.7   1.026379276 196.982 1.69    8   14  548.525 -8.8
 16. 16 328.95  314.03  1.047511384 125.069 1.47    4   9   339.324 -6.9
 17. 17 451.68  444.63  1.01585588  118.025 1.6     5   10  466.47  -9.4
 18. 18 469.67  466.11  1.007637682 130.99  1.62    5   11  486.501 -8.3
 19. 19 500.79  498.09  1.005420707 146.805 1.65    6   12  525.538 -9.8
 20. 20 476.59  473.03  1.00752595  149.821 1.62    6   12  502.5   -8.4
 21. 21 357.84  347.14  1.030823299 138.147 1.5     5   10  378.361 -8.6
 22. 22 484.15  477.28  1.014394066 129.93  1.64    6   11  505.507 -10.2
 23. 23 502.15  498.71  1.006897796 142.918 1.65    6   12  525.538 -9.3
 24. 24 526.73  530.31  0.993249232 154.106 1.66    7   13  564.575 -9.9
 25. 25 509.34  505.64  1.007317459 161.844 1.66    7   13  541.537 -9.2
 26. 26 337.53  320.98  1.051560845 144.797 1.49    5   10  355.323 -7.1
 27. 27 460.25  451.58  1.019199256 137.732 1.62    5   11  482.469 -9.6
 28. 28 478.4   473.25  1.010882198 155.442 1.63    6   12  502.5   -8.9
 29. 29 507.62  505.68  1.003836418 161.884 1.65    6   13  541.537 -9.2
 30. 30 482.27  479.07  1.006679608 171.298 1.63    7   13  518.499 -9.1
 31.V0L 355.19  333.42  1.065293024 59.105  1.530   0   9   345.37  -10.4
```

- Su = Surface Area in squared angstrom
- Vol = Volume in cubic angstrom
- PSA = Polar Surface Area in squared angstrom
- Ov = Ovality
- D= Number of Hydrogen Bond Donating group
- A = Number of Hydrogen Bond Donating group
- Vina = Binding affinity (lower is better)
- Mw = Molecular Weight
- Mol = The number of molecule candidate

Comment: Where is `drug V0L ` in your data please ?

Comment: the last row. 31th row.

Comment: D and A have identical definitions, but do not contain the same values.

Comment: what do you mean by that? what's D and A.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your question is missing an important ingredient: How do YOU define "most similar"? The answer suggesting euclidean distance is bad because it doesn't even suggest normalizing the data. You should also obviously discard the numbering column when computing the distance.

Once you have defined your distance in some mathematical form, it's a simple matter of computing the distance between the candidate molecules and the target.

Some considerations for defining the distance measure:

1. I'd suggest *normalizing* each column in some way. Otherwise, a column with large values will dominate over those with smaller values. Popular ways of normalizing include scaling everything into the range "0, 1" or alternatively shifting and scaling so that the mean is 0 and the standard deviation is 1.
2. Make sure to get rid of "id"-type columns when computing your distance
3. After normalization, all columns will truly contribute the same weight. The way to change that depends on your measure but easiest is to just element-wise multiply the columns with factors to emphasize or de-emphasize them.

For the details, using `pandas` and/or `numpy` is the way to go here.

Comment: @lagerbear thank you. I would consider that advice. It would pretty much satisfy my need.

Answer (score -1):

In order to find the most similar molecule we can use `euclidean` distance between all rows and the last one, and pick up the row having minimal distance value:

```
# make the last row as a new dataframe named `df1`

df1 = df[30:31]

# And the first rows in another dataframe:

df2 = df[0:31]
```

And use `scipy.spatial` package :

```
import scipy.spatial
ary = scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(df2, df1, metric='euclidean')
df2[ary==ary.min()]
```

**Output**

This output is by using the previous dataframe before new edits of the question :

```
    Molecule    SurfaceAr   Volume  PSA Ovality HBD HBA Mw  Vina BA Su/Vol
15  RiboseGly   1.047511    314.03  125.069 1.47    4   9   339.324 -6.9    0.003336
```

Comment: Aha, okay. THANKS ALOT. but in this case, I guess all factors contribute equally to choosing the most similar. how can we consider a coefficient for each factor for calculating the most similar? in order to make some factors more important and some less.

Comment: You're welcome @Muzeita , you can add `distance` column by doing : `df2['distance'] = ary`, as a second step you store the sorted dataframe in a `new_df`, the code is : `new_df = df2.sort_values(by='distance')` you will get rows sorted from the one having minimal distance to that having max distance

Comment: And I think, there might be a misunderstanding here. when I said having different coefficients I was talking about, making some factors more important and some less. as an example making binding affinity more important than PSA. like binding affinity contributes more to the final answer. I'm not sure if making it more clear or not.

Comment: when I run this code it would find the drug itself as the closet.